# I'm trying to solve an OR problem written using pulp framework , with gurobi, in Linux , but I'm not able to solve it

Tags: gurobi, pulp, windows

I'm trying to solve an OR problem written using pulp framework , with gurobi, in Linux , but I'm not able to solve it . In windows,I use this command to use gurobi ,

```
if solver == gurobi :

 path = 'gurobi.exe'

 solver = pulp.GUROBI_CMD(path=path, msg=1)
```

However in Linux there is no .exe file , how do I approach this?

Comment: Does [this](https://coin-or.github.io/pulp/guides/how_to_configure_solvers.html) page help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `path` in Linux has to point to the `gurobi_cl` binary, which is located in the `bin` folder. Therefore, you should try

```
path = r'<path-to-gurobi>/bin/gurobi_cl'
```